# I don't understand CE Cache breaking

Tags: ce-cache

I try to implement ce cache so that everytime **any** entry is updated/deleted/added the cache is rewritten.

So I read trough the documentation and diverse forum posts. But I don't get it.

Lets say I have a template:

```
{exp:ce_cache:it id="news" url_prefix="{language_code}" tags="news"
   {exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
      {title}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:ce_cache:it}
```

Now I added `tags="news"` like so:

[image]

Now when I edit an new entry shouldn't it break the cache and show up the edited news entry? Well it doesn't.

I use the file driver.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct - this is how cache breaking works with CE Cache. It could be that your server is having trouble clearing the file driver cache. Can you clear the cache manually with success?

Comment: Yes I can clear it manually. Is this a server adjustment thing? Does my sysadmin have to activate something serverside?

Comment: If you can clear it manually then the cache breaking should work. I'd file a support ticket with Aaron: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-cache/viewforum/1867